# Error with content being read out of file

Tags: c, file, struct

Hello fellow programmers i am trying to understand what exactly is happening in this area of my code.
Problem: I read some contents into a file , then i am trying to read back the contents out of the file just to make sure its the right contents i had put into the file but it is not giving me the correct output, so i am a little confused here is the code(saved content as binary) :

```
typedef struct acc
{
 int id_no;
 int pin;
 float bal;
}Acc;

int Crte_acc(FILE *flepss)
{
  int i,cnt;
  Acc user[1000];
  cnt = 1000;

  for (i=1;i<1000;i++)
 {
    cnt+=1;
    user[i].id_no = cnt;
    user[i].bal=1000;
    user[i].pin=0000;
    fwrite(&user[i].id_no,sizeof(int),1,flepss);
    fwrite(&user[i].pin,sizeof(int),1,flepss);
fwrite(&user[i].bal,sizeof(int),1,flepss);
 }
  return fclose(flepss);
}
```

Yea so above is the code that takes a file pointer and a count to keep the id to increase by 1 ( 1001,1002 etc), bal and pin required that i set the var with those digits.So i am wondering whats the problem, this is the code of me displaying the contents.

```
void DisplyFile()
{
  FILE *dfp;
  int x;
  Acc pruser[1000];
  dfp = fopen("Account.dat","rb");
  fseek(dfp,0,SEEK_SET);
      while (1)
 {
    if(!feof(dfp))
    {

        for (x=1;x<1000;x++)
        {
            fread(&pruser[x].id_no,sizeof(pruser[x].id_no),1,dfp);
            fread(&pruser[x].pin,sizeof(pruser[x].pin),1,dfp);
            fread(&pruser[x].bal,sizeof(pruser[x].bal),1,dfp);
            printf("%d  ",pruser[x].id_no);
            printf("%d  ",pruser[x].pin);
            printf("%.2f\n\n",pruser[x].bal);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
 }
}
```

EDIT: By contents coming out wrong i mean , giving me garbage values as to show that my write to file was not saved.

Comment: How did you create/open the file when you write to it?

Comment: fp=fopen(acc,"wb"); where acc is "Account.dat" just passed the fp to crte_acc

Comment: You are saying it is not giving you the right content, can you elaborate on that part?

Comment: Which size has `Account.dat`?

Comment: @alk could you rephrase that for me

Comment: Could you try to add a `fclose()` at the end of the read function ? Another point is `fwrite(&user[i].bal,sizeof(int),1,flepss);`...`bla` is a float.

Comment: After `Account.dat` had been written to disk. Which size does the file have in the file system, as reported by `ls` (UNIX) or `dir` (DOS)?

Comment: @francis: You should make the second part of your comment an answer!

Comment: omg really * facepalm * cant believe i didn't pick up on that *face palm * yea make it a answer plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may come from a missing fclose or fopen...
There is almost nothing to do to build something that works.

Three things to check :

-Does a `fopen` correspond to a `fclose` ?

-Are opening types similar ? Are both "wb" and "rb" used ?

-Another point is `fwrite(&user[i].bal,sizeof(int),1,flepss);`...`bla` is a float. float and int may have the same `sizeof`, but...It is safer to assume that it is not always the case !

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct acc
{
    int id_no;
    int pin;
    float bal;
}Acc;

int Crte_acc()
{
    FILE *flepss;
    int i,cnt;
    Acc user[10];
    cnt = 1000;
    flepss = fopen("Account.dat","wb");
    for (i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        cnt+=1;
        user[i].id_no = cnt;
        user[i].bal=10;
        user[i].pin=0000;
        fwrite(&user[i].id_no,sizeof(int),1,flepss);
        fwrite(&user[i].pin,sizeof(int),1,flepss);
        fwrite(&user[i].bal,sizeof(float),1,flepss);
    }
    return fclose(flepss);
}

void DisplyFile()
{
    FILE *dfp;
    int x;
    Acc pruser[10];
    dfp = fopen("Account.dat","rb");
    fseek(dfp,0,SEEK_SET);
    while (1)
    {
        if(!feof(dfp))
        {

            for (x=1;x<10;x++)
            {
                fread(&pruser[x].id_no,sizeof(pruser[x].id_no),1,dfp);
                fread(&pruser[x].pin,sizeof(pruser[x].pin),1,dfp);
                fread(&pruser[x].bal,sizeof(pruser[x].bal),1,dfp);
                printf("%d  ",pruser[x].id_no);
                printf("%d  ",pruser[x].pin);
                printf("%.2f\n\n",pruser[x].bal);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(dfp);
}

int main()
{

    Crte_acc();
    printf("file printed\n");

    DisplyFile();
    printf("end file read 1\n");
    DisplyFile();
    printf("end file read 2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

To compile : `gcc main.c -o main`

Bye,